# How do I access jQuery Mobile <select> elements in PHP?

Tags: php, forms, jquery-mobile

I have a popup select box in a form in my jQuery Mobile application.

```
<div data-role='fieldcontain'>
    <label for='fruits' class='select'>Favorite Fruits</label>
    <select name='fruits' id='fruits' multiple='multiple' data-native-menu='false'>
        <option>Favorite Fruits</option>
        <option value='1' checked='checked'>Apple</option>
        <option value='2' checked='checked'>Banana</option>
        <option value='3' checked='checked'>Cherry</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

The value attributes of the option elements are equal to the database IDs of the fruits. After the form is submitted, I try to access the array of elements selected with

```
$fruits = $_POST['fruits'];
```

However, `var_dump($fruits)` issues an error noting that $fruits is not defined. Why?

Comment: Also, `checked='checked'` is not working in that it is not getting those options selected by default. I'm working that out too.

Comment: pretty sure you use selected="selected" for select boxes...

Comment: Thank you! That solves one problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some tinkering I think you have three issues:

- select box name should be `name="fruits[]`
- `checked="checked"` should be `selected="selected"`
- empty options should be `value=""`